# Method to instantiate a "painted" UICollectionViewCell subclass outside of the UICollectionView API?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a functioning UICollectionView with dequed reusable tiles, that I laid out in XCode. I'm trying to do a drag-drop thing, where I effectively duplicate an instance of my custom UICollectionViewCell subclass, but for use in a view outside of the originating UICollectionView. Is there a general strategy for this?

I added an `init(frame:CGRect)` so that I could create it outside of the UICollectionView use case, but then I don't get the incantation that comes from the coder. Is there an API I can use to get a coder specific for that reuseIdentifer and create one with it, rather than through the `UICollectionView.deque` API?

(I'm doing Swift3/iOS10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be able to create `UICollectionViewCell` instanced without bothering `UICollectionView`, define your `UICollectionViewCell` in a `XIB`, not in Storyboard.

To do do this in Xcode:

- File -> New -> File -> User Interface -> View
- Set its class to `NameOfYourCellClass` just like you do in Storyboard.

To use it in your `ViewController`, you have to register the XIB:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
   //...        
    self.collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "nameOfXibFileWithoutExtension", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier")
}
```

Now the collectionView should work like before, but you can also create independent versions of your cell from anywhere in your project:

```
private func instantiateCellFromNib() -> NameOfYourCellClass {
    let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "nameOfXibFileWithoutExtension", bundle: bundle)
    let cell = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! NameOfYourCellClass

    return cell
}
```